# Sql server jdbc driver trying to connect via wrong username. JDBC using integrated security/windows authentication and username,password

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have upgrade from JTDS driver to Sql server JDBC driver 4.1 and trying to connect to Sql server database using following connection string

```
jdbc:sqlserver://<System_IP>;instance=MSSQLSERVER;domain=domainname;IntegratedSecurity=true;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;selectMethod=cursor;user=administrator;password=pass
```

It's failing with error message:
**Login failed for user domainname/current_machinename.**

1. This connection was working fine till I upgraded to JDBC driver 4.1
2. Why JDBC is trying to connect via domainname/current_machinename. It should have been domainname/administrator which I am passing in connection string.

Comment: Integrated security uses the credentials of the user executing the process; you can't provide a username and password to use that way.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel
Is there any way / hack to provide username and password the way I want.
Also I am not sure how it was working with jtds driver

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 at the end

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Tried authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos; Then it's failing with error: Integrated authentication failed.

Comment: Found out that it is not currently supported and currently under investigation.
https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/696